# How to change href address on each button click?

Tags: counter, whatsapp

I run a website that has a click-to-chat Whatsapp button and we have 3 customer representatives to answer chats. What I want to do is changing Whatsapp number for each individual click to send equal customers to each customer representative. I know I require some kind of counter but value of the counter has to be stored somewhere so when a different customer visits the site counter should continue where the last customer left off.

I kinda figure what to do but not how to do. Should it be php or js i don't know. I need help.

For a better visualisation:

if {counter = 0}
`<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123>`
else if {counter = 1}
`<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=456>`
else if {counter = 2}
`<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=789>`

Thanks in advance.